# Merge cells and count their adjacent values

Tags: excel

It's been years since I've used excel.

What I have is this:

```
COLUMN 1   COLUMN 2
TOURPLAN   £200
TOURPLAN   £300
CATCH      £50
LEX        £75
CATCH      £100
```

I need to merge all the same names in column one and then total their values to the right.

I can't remember how to do this, so would love some guidance!

Comment: Use Pivot Tables. Merged cells are annoying if you want to work with functions or filters. Resum your data with Pivot Tables. You could group your data by Field 1 and sum up values from column 2.

Comment: Pivot tables is your most straightforward answer. Go with that! Otherwise there is the option to copy column 1 into column 3, remove duplicates, and in column 4 use a formula to sum column 2 based on criteria in column 3

Comment: Awesome. That worked a treat.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to Foxfire And Burns And Burns and JvDV who pointed out to use pivot tables, worked a treat.